# React-native ListView with Navigation

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, navigation

I am trying to use component ListView with Navigation but I get undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.props.navigator') error

My ListView is in Contacts.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, ListView, Text, View, Navigator  } from 'react-native';
import Row from './Row'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'
import Sections from './Sections'
import Load from './Load'
import demoData from './data'
import Pagination from '../Pagination';

export default class Contacts extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionId) => dataBlob[sectionId];
        const getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[`${rowId}`];

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
          sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
          getSectionData,
          getRowData,
        });

        const { dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds } = this.formatData(demoData);

        // Init state
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds),
            left: true,
            center: false,
            right: false
        }
    }

formatData(data) {
    // We're sorting by alphabetically so we need the alphabet
    const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');

    // Need somewhere to store our data
    const dataBlob = {};
    const sectionIds = [];
    const rowIds = [];

    // Each section is going to represent a letter in the alphabet so we loop over the alphabet
    for (let sectionId = 0; sectionId < alphabet.length; sectionId++) {
        // Get the character we're currently looking for
        const currentChar = alphabet[sectionId];

        // Get users whose first name starts with the current letter
        const users = data.filter((user) => user.name.first.toUpperCase().indexOf(currentChar) === 0);

        // If there are any users who have a first name starting with the current letter then we'll
        // add a new section otherwise we just skip over it
        if (users.length > 0) {
            // Add a section id to our array so the listview knows that we've got a new section
            sectionIds.push(sectionId);

            // Store any data we would want to display in the section header. In our case we want to show
            // the current character
            dataBlob[sectionId] = { character: currentChar };

            // Setup a new array that we can store the row ids for this section
            rowIds.push([]);

            // Loop over the valid users for this section
            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                // Create a unique row id for the data blob that the listview can use for reference
                const rowId = `${sectionId}:${i}`;

                // Push the row id to the row ids array. This is what listview will reference to pull
                // data from our data blob
                rowIds[rowIds.length - 1].push(rowId);

                // Store the data we care about for this row
                dataBlob[rowId] = users[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return { dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.contactsContainer} >
                <Pagination 
                    left={this.state.left}
                    center={this.state.center}
                    right={this.state.right}
                />
                <ListView
                style={styles.listContainer}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} navigator={this.props.Navigator} />}
                renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
                renderHeader={() => <SearchBar />}
                renderFooter={() => <Load />}
                renderSectionHeader={(sectionData) => <Sections {...sectionData} />}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contactsContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
    listContainer: {
        marginTop: 10
    },
    separator: {
        flex: 1,
        height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
    }
});
```

**Line**

renderRow={(data) => }

calls Row.js and prints contacts data

```
import React from 'react';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen'
import { AppRegistry, View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, Alert, Navigator } from 'react-native';

const Row = (props) => (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.Navigator.push({ screen: 'ProfileScreen' })} underlayColor="#FFFFFF">
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <View style={ styles.status } />
            <Text style={ styles.text }>
                {`${ props.name.first } ${ props.name.last }`}
            </Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 12,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        marginLeft: 12,
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    status: {
        backgroundColor: '#5cb85c',
        height: 10,
        width: 10,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
});

export default Row;
```

As you can see each row has a TouchableHighlight when pressed it should navigate to ProfileScreen

**EDIT**

**DO NOT USE NAVIGATOR IT IS DEPRECIATED INSTED USE STACKNAVIGATOR**

Comment: Please post the parent component where `navigator` is defined.

Comment: I have navigator defined on each file. I posted the whole file so you could see it.

Comment: Did the below answer resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use this.props.Navigator when you are importing the Navigator module. Just use Navigator. `this.props` contains the list of all the attributes that you pass on to a component

Eg:

**Parent.js**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <Child firstProp={"FirstProp"} secondProps={"SecondProp"} />
  }
}
```

**Child.js**

```
import {externalImport} from './externalFile'

class Child extends React.Component{
  render() {
    <div>
       I AM FIRST PROP {this.props.firstProp}
       I AM SECOND PROP {this.props.secondProp}
       I AM NOT A PROP, JUST AN IMPORT { externalImport }
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but I found out that Navigator is depreciated.